# Image pull back off - Openshift

Tags: kubernetes, openshift

I keep getting the error of imagepullback off when pods are created.

The image tag is correct and I have deleted the pods but I get the same error. I tried all the other suggestions here but don't understand the issue.

```
Back-off pulling image "docker-registry.svc.us.com/f90-1/image:1.1.1"
```

Any suggestions for fix?

Comment: Does that image registry exist? `docker-registry.svc.us.com`

Comment: yes it does . Also throws this error -Failed to pull image "docker-registry.svc.us.com/f90-1/image:1.1.1": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error: image f90-1/image:1.1.1 not found" .The image is there, any ideas how can i troubleshoot?

Comment: Is `docker-registry.svc.us.com` a private registry? If so, do you have access to pull images from it? Can you link to the image in question?

Comment: as mentioned in the previous comment you may need to add an image pull secret specifying the registry FQDN and credentials for it

Answer (score 0):

The "oc describe pod " commands should give you more details as to way the  image pull fails.